# PHP PDO Fetch too slow from remote PostgreSQL server

Tags: postgresql, pdo, amazon-rds

I have some remote PostgreSQL server at AWS service. Is about 200ms away from my location. A table include just 70 records.

Making query on this database `select * from table` require less than a second. But, fetching all these records require 12 seconds. That is too much.

If I use PDO ::fetch function, then it return records one after one but total time is 12 seconds .

Alternatively ::fetchAll function return all data at once BUT again 12 seconds .

I understand that it work in both cases downloading record by record . and 200 ms for query + 200 ms response ... so on .

BUT psql show same query response almost immediately , so it fetch all results and show it .

MySQL at same distance run much much faster via PDO .

Is there way to increase fetching speed ? may be way to force driver to download whole data from the server at once ? ::fetchAll seem work same "record after record" fetching and does not help at all.

Comment: Are you connecting internally (i.e. using a local IP address in your VPC) or an external IP address (which means going over the internet).

Answer (score 0):

After various tests I found that is just slow . Thats all. use pgsql driver , not PDO . May be in future they will do it faster .